# typescript code to write the generate content into a new created file

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

Right now I am developing a VS Code extension, I want to store the generate HTML code into a system auto-created HTML file, but I dont know how to do this in typescript, please help, thanks a lot

Comment: you want to know how to write HTML to file using ts??

Comment: for now our program will generate HTML code, but it will open another vscode window, I have to manually save it as an HTML file, I just want to know is there anyway to auto-generate an HTML file with the given HTML code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly related to Typescript, but to node-js itself.

You could utilize **fs module** from node ( either use writeFile or writeFileSync), like this -

```js
import { writeFile } from "fs";

const saveToFile = async (filePath: string) => Promise<void> {
  await writeFile(filePath, dataToWrite, err => console.log(err));
}
```

Could use following references -
[Writing files with NodeJs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/writing-files-with-nodejs)